# Google Analytics: Moving Profile to Top-Level Account

Tags: google-analytics

For historical reasons some profiles were set up under one account. At a later time new sites were added in their own accounts. I am wanting to move some profiles out from under the account they are currently under and into their own accounts. I cannot figure out how to do this and have scoured the help files looking for how this is accomplished. Anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe what you're trying to accomplish is possible. You collect data under a unique ID (UA - ID) this is called a property. Off of that property you can build profiles to *view* a subset of data. Profile can be recreated under a new property, but it wouldn't have any historical data.

For more info, you can check out - https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts

Comment: BUMMER. I was hoping there was a way around having to walk away from historical data to accomplish it. Thank you for the response, though.